# Query max value for each column type from multiple tables

Tags: sql

I have a table that keeps track of a a group's score as well as their player's personal information. I need to obtain the maximum score value for each id (group), while keeping the personal information the same. The SQL I used was:

```
SELECT A.GROUP_ID, B.PLAYER_SCORE, A.PLAYER_EMAIL, A.PLAYER_NUMBER      
FROM PLAYER_INFO A,
     SCORE_INFO B,
     ID_INFO C      
WHERE (B.PLAYER_NUMBER = A.PLAYER_NUMBER)           
  AND (B.GROUP_ID = A.GROUP_ID)           
  AND (A.GROUP_ID = C.GROUP_ID)
```

and this is the table I get something like this

```
| GROUP ID | Player Score | Player Email      | Player Number 
| ---------| ------------ | ----------------- | -------------
| 1        | 200          | player1@gmail.com | 1-332-301837  
| 1        | 300          | player2@gmail.com | 1-332-3423 
| 1        | 100          | player3@gmail.com | 1-332-54253 
| 3        | 200          | player4@gmail.com | 1-332-1153425 
| 2        | 150          | player5@gmail.com | 1-332-23521 
| 2        | 280          | player6@gmail.com | 1-332-2224 
| 2        | 315          | player7@gmail.com | 1-332-1543
```

I am trying to get the max player score from each group, while keeping the player email and number the same, so the output of my table should look like this:

```
| GROUP ID | Player Score | Player Email      | Player Number 
| -------- | -------------| ----------------- | ------------- 
| 1        | 300          | player2@gmail.com | 1-332-3423 
| 2        | 315          | player7@gmail.com | 1-332-1543 
| 3        | 200          | player4@gmail.com | 1-332-1153425
```

If anyone could help me achieve the table to look like such, that would be great. Thanks

I tried to run the query with MAX(B.PLAYER_SCORE) in the query but I was still receiving duplicate entries for the groups

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using? Please do not spam-tag multiple, tag the single RDBMS you are using.

Comment: MySQL <> SqlServer <> Postgresql. Tag only the proper one. Also, if MySql, then state your version. You can likely use a `row_number()` window function. Search SO for something like "max per group" to find several answers.

Comment: I highly recommend not using that old style implicit join and instead use modern explicit joins.

Comment: Finally please provide a [mre] with sample data in addition to your desired results.

Comment: `A`, `B` and `C` are poor table aliases. Choose something that makes sense, e.g. `P` for `PLAYERS`. (And who do every table end with `_INFO`?!?)

Comment: why do you have group id stored in all three tables?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that's PostgreSQL, you're probably after [`distinct on`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT):

```sql
select distinct on (b.player_score)
   a.group_id, b.player_score, a.player_email, a.player_number
from player_info a 
inner join score_info b using(player_number,group_id)
inner join id_info    c using(group_id)
order by b.player_score desc
```

1. All [identifiers](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS) are folded to lowercase, unless you double-quote them.
2. If your column names match, you can list each of them once in [`join...using()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-FROM).